# Zoho OAUTH_SCOPE_MISMATCH error when uploading file through Zoho CRM API

Tags: zoho

I keep getting an "OAUTH_SCOPE_MISMATCH" error when trying to Upload an Attachment to a lead using API V2.(Zoho CRM)
This is the documentation I am using: https://www.zoho.com/crm/developer/docs/api/v2/upload-attachment.html

I set the scope when making the Authorization Request to generate Grant Token, and with that token, I am able to obtain access and refresh the token. With the refresh token, I am able to get the final token to pass as "Zoho-oauthtoken" in the final post.

I am not getting an Authorization error so I think that part is working.
I have been able to create new Leads but not attach docs.

Here are the different scopes I have tried with no luck.

```
ZohoCRM.modules.leads.CREATE,ZohoCRM.modules.attachments.CREATE
ZohoCRM.modules.leads.UPDATE,ZohoCRM.modules.attachments.ALL
```

If I use the Scopes: `ZohoCRM.modules.leads.ALL,ZohoCRM.modules.attachments.ALL`
I am able to successfully send attachments however I do not want to set the scope to `ZohoCRM.modules.ALL` because I am sending to a 3rd party and I only want this org. to be able to create new leads and attach documents to the lead. They should not be able to Read/Delete any lead data.

the URL I'm posting to looks like this: https://www.zohoapis.com/crm/v2/Leads/426877xxx(LeadID)xxx937/Attachments

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!